# Cannot import csv file data to table in latex using csvsimple

Tags: csv, csvsimple

I don't know why the data rows not shows up. Only the header, here is my csv file:

```
method,name,error,occurences
socket,socket,"ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer')",12
socket,socket,"CryptoError('Decryption failed. Ciphertext failed verification',)",60
socket,socket,"SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:748)')",77
socket,socket,"ConnectionRefusedError(61, 'Connection refused')",992
socket,socket,"BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe')",3
```

And my MWE:

```
\begin{document}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{datatool}  
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption[Table~\ref{fig:socketdropconnerr} Error during socket test]{Error during socket test}
    \vspace{0.2cm}    
    \label{fig:drop-error-socket}
    \begin{tabular}{ l l }%
        \toprule error & occurences \\
        \csvreader[head to column names]{csv/dropped-conn/error-socket.csv}{}%
        {\\\hline\error & \occurences}%
        \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the content of your error column. The package seems to not understand the stuff contained in surrounding `"`s to be one cell. The result is that it ignores the lines it can't parse, and since this is true for all lines, every line is ignored.

Instead of using `"` to denote a cell containing commas, use curly brackets. Also the underscore doesn't work here, you'd have to escape it using `\`. The following would work:

CSV:

```
method,name,error,occurences
socket,socket,{ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer')},12
socket,socket,{CryptoError('Decryption failed. Ciphertext failed verification',)},60
socket,socket,{SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (\_ssl.c:748)')},77
socket,socket,{ConnectionRefusedError(61, 'Connection refused')},992
socket,socket,{BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe')},3
```

TeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{datatool}  
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption[Table~\ref{fig:socketdropconnerr} Error during socket test]{Error during socket test}
    \vspace{0.2cm}    
    \label{fig:drop-error-socket}
    \begin{tabular}{ l l }%
        \toprule error & occurences \\
        \midrule
        \csvreader[late after line=\\,head to column
        names]{data3.csv}{}%
        {\error & \occurences}%
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why even use `csvsimple` here? `datatool` can read the data just fine, all extra needed is to escape that `_`

Comment: @daleif because he used `csvsimple` and asked why it doesn't work. And take a look at egreg's answer for that underscore (didn't know that, just took a quick look into the documentation when I wrote my answer).

Answer (score 2):

If entries of the CSV file contain commas, it's best to use a different separator.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
method;name;error;occurences
socket;socket;ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer');12
socket;socket;CryptoError('Decryption failed. Ciphertext failed verification',);60
socket;socket;SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:748)');77
socket;socket;ConnectionRefusedError(61, 'Connection refused');992
socket;socket;BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe');3
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{Error during socket test}
\label{fig:drop-error-socket}

\vspace{0.2cm}    

\csvreader[
  head to column names,
  separator=semicolon,
  tabular=ll,
  table head=\toprule error & occurrences \\ \midrule,
  table foot=\bottomrule,
  respect underscore,
]{\jobname.csv}{}
{\error & \occurences}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

See also the `respect underscore` option for avoiding problems with `_`.

I used `filecontents*` only to make the example self-contained.

[image]

Comment: Did not know that extra option, though datatool does not seem to have issues with the original data (at least after escaping the `_`)